# Cannot Uninstall Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server

Cannot Uninstall Sharepoint 2016 using control panel, after i click change/uninstall nothing happens.

Is there any other way to uninstall ?

Comment: Control panel process should work, but [Verify that you are a member of the Farm Administrators group or a member of the Administrators group on the local computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/uninstall-sharepoint-server-2016).

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you could uninstall other apps in control panel.

You could also reboot the server and try again to check the result.

Here is an article about how to uninstall SharePoint server completely for your reference:

[How to Uninstall SharePoint 2013 - Complete Steps](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/05/how-to-uninstall-sharepoint-2013.html)(Also apply to SharePoint 2016)